# How could one defeat Webtrackers

Tags: web-application, http, user-tracking

I was just wondering why some pages refuse to load completely while surfing with no-script Plug-in when I don’t allow specific Java scripts. I was wondering if there is some way to hold the tracker scripts blocked without resulting in broken web pages. So I tried some other "don't track" plug-ins and tried to find some knowledge. Most of the "don't track" plugins make some pages not work. So I was wondering how one could defeat such trackers like googleanalytics or piwik or such. I was just wondering for Privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Evercookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie) is able to track users using 15 different methods, and if parts are removed then it automatically recreates the missing data. Edward Snowden cited it as a method effectively used to track the otherwise untrackable [TOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) users. You could theoretically make a new virtual machine for each browsing session and delete it when done, but you'll still have to mask your IP address and prune your [user-agent string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to keep from potentially being recognized from your previous visits.

Practically, you need to balance your desire to browse a specific wab page against your desire to remain untracked. There's no way to automatically determine which parts of the JavaScript ([not Java scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)) are being used for tracking and which are for functionality; you'd have to open each script and determine it manually for every page you visit. You can do a lot by disabling cookies by default, disabling scripts by default, and setting plugins as click-to-run, but you cannot get around the fact that many sites today force you to allow them to track you in order to access their content.

If you're blocking scripts by default, keeping googleanalytics scripts and cookies blocked (and, obviously, not signing into your google account) will generally be enough to stop google from tracking you. I don't have any experience with piwik, so I can't speak to that.